# Windows PowerShell: Get-FileHash and long file paths

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, path, checksum

**OS is Windows 10.**

I'm using PowerShell's "Get-FileHash" command to generate a file's MD5 checksum directly within its folder, like so:

```
PS Z:\Test> Get-FileHash 'test.txt' -algorithm MD5                                                                      
Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path
---------       ----                                                                   ----
MD5             D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E                                       Z:\Test\test.txt
```

However, when long file paths are involved, PowerShell seems unable to find the file trough Get-FileHash.

```
PS Z:\Test loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong> Get-FileHash 'looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong.txt' -algorithm MD5                                                                                                                Resolve-Path : Cannot find path 'Z:\Test looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong\looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
oooong.txt' because it does not exist.
At C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psm1:11
0 char:36
+                 $pathsToProcess += Resolve-Path $Path | Foreach-Objec ...
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Z:\Test loooooo...ooooooooong.txt:String) [Resolve-Path], ItemNotFoundE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ResolvePathCommand
```

On the other hand, it's perfectly able to find the file using "Get-ChildItem":

```
PS Z:\Test loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong> Get-ChildItem


    Directory: Z:\Test looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
    ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
    oooooooooooooooooooooooooong


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2024-02-26     12:55              0 loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
                                                  ooooooooooong.txt
```

**How do I generate MD5:s in these kind of cases? I don't have administrative privileges.**

Comment: (There's nothing wrong with the "loooooooo...ng.txt"-file, as it works fine within a shorter folder name:)

    PS Z:\Test> Get-FileHash 'looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong.txt' -algorithm MD5
    
    Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path
    ---------       ----                                                                   ----
    MD5             D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E                                       Z:\Test\loooooooooooooooooooo...

Comment: Try piping the output of `Get-ChildItem` to `Get-FileHash` as followed: `Get-ChildItem * -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5`.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Hmmm I can't get that to work. If I do "Get-ChildItem * "-test.txt" | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5, I just get a new empty line. If I do it without the quotes around  the file name, it throws "Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'test'."

Comment: IF you are looking for text files only, It should be `Get-ChildItem "*.txt" -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5`.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Sorry, I mistook "-File" as an instruction for me to input the name of a particular file I wanted an MD5 for. I see now that the command gets the checksum for all files in the folder. It's more convenient to input than Cpt.Whale's answer, even if it's obviously a lot less precise. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I'm afraid it doesn't work with the long paths though, same error as if you input it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an extended-length path by prepending `\\?\` to it and using the `-LiteralPath` parameter, like:

```sh
# local path
Get-FileHash -LiteralPath '\\?\C:\long\path\to\file.txt'

# network share
Get-FileHash -LiteralPath '\\?\UNC\server\share\folder\file.txt'
```

This convinces most programs to accept long path names, and does not require admin permissions.

See more information in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21194605/7411885

Comment: Thank you, that works.

Follow-up question: Why doesn't PowerShell throw an explicit error about the file path being too long, e.g. like in this reddit post?

https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/11a56i4/getchilditem_and_getacl_not_working_with_local/

"Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

Comment: @user1763606 the `Get-FileHash` command likely just relies on a different part of the windows API that doesn't check for path length. All it knows is the OS couldn't find the file